Step Line plot result using Syminfo.tickerid in pine script
I have been having this issue, if anyone could shed light on it, it would be greatly appreciated :)

I want to make an indicator and have several time frames inside one indicator so i can not use timeframe_gap cause it would only result in one timeframe inside the indicator.

-- I also cant use Line.new cause it would not return value for all the history of the chart.

I have reached to request.security(syminfo.tickerid,'D', RSI)

which is fine for returning value for all time frames that I need inside one time frame , < but using Plot which can not be conditioned give a Stepline result for every candle which has not yet closed in higher time frames.
How can I resolve this result to get a continuous line other than the step line ?
thank you in advance :)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
